# How to apply custom percent change to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I would like to apply custom percentages to my dataframe rows and last row per each company id should always be zero. I tried with df.apply method but not able to pass multiple parameters. Appreciate if you could let me know in how many ways this problem can be solved? Thank you in advance for your attention and efforts!!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyId' : ['A','A','A','B','B'],                           
                 'stand_alone' : [10,12,-5,20,1]})

def get_change(current,previous):
    if current==previous:
        return 0
    if current>=0 and previous<0:
        chg=1.0
    if current>=0 and previous==0:
        chg=1.0
    if current<0 and previous>0:
        chg=-1.0
    if current>0 and previous>0:
        chg=abs(current)/abs(previous)-1
    if current<0 and previous<0:
        chg=abs(current)/abs(previous)-1
        chg=-chg
    return round(chg*100,2)
```

Output should be as follows:

```
CompanyId change    stand_alone
    0   A   -16.67  10
    1   A   100.00  12
    2   A   0.00    -5
    3   B   1900.00 20
    4   B   0.00    1
```

Comment: Why do you use abs if current>0 and previous>0?

Comment: I might remove the abs. You may ignore it. I am yet to fully develop my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is one way to do it using your current logic.

```
def get_change(x):
    x=x.sort_index(ascending=False)
    cond1 = x == x.shift(1)
    result1 = 0
    cond2 = (x < 0) & x.shift(1) > 0
    result2 = -1
    cond3 = ((x>0) & (x.shift(1)>0)) | ((x<0) & (x.shift(1)<0))
    result3 = (x/x.shift(1)) - 1
    cond4 = ((x>=0)&(x.shift(1)<=0)) 
    result4 = 1
    result = np.select([cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4],[result1,result2,result3,result4])*100
    return result[::-1]

df['change'] = df.groupby('CompanyId')['stand_alone'].transform(get_change).round(2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  CompanyId  stand_alone   change
0         A           10   -16.67
1         A           12   100.00
2         A           -5     0.00
3         B           20  1900.00
4         B            1     0.00
```

I think the key functions you need to use with this approach are `np.select` a way of doing if-then-elseif logic and `groupby` with `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and direct way to do it to add column with previous values as shift of current. 
Avoid `apply` on rows is last thing you can do because of very low performance (slightly effective than for over rows)

```py
df  = df.assign(previous =  df.groupby('CompanyId').stand_alone.shift(-1)
               ).assign(chg = np.NaN)

df.loc[(df.stand_alone - df.previous)<1e-5,'chg'] = 0 #equal for float
df.loc[(df.stand_alone >= 0)&(df.previous <=0),'chg'] = 1.
df.loc[(df.stand_alone < 0)&(df.previous >0),'chg'] = -1.
mask = (df.stand_alone > 0)&(df.previous >0)
df.loc[mask,'chg'] = np.abs(df[mask].stand_alone/df[mask].previous)-1
mask = (df.stand_alone < 0)&(df.previous <0)
df.loc[mask,'chg'] = -np.abs(df[mask].stand_alone/df[mask].previous)+1
df['chg'] = np.round( df.chg.fillna(0)*100,2)
df.drop(columns=['previous'],inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

```py
    CompanyId   stand_alone chg
    0   A   10  -16.67
    1   A   12  100.0
    2   A   -5  0.0
    3   B   20  1900.0
    4   B   1   0.0
```

But you might do it with small changes in your code

```py
def get_change(x):
    current = x['stand_alone']
    previous = x['previous']
    chg=0
    if current==previous:
        return 0
    if current>=0 and previous<0:
        chg=1.0
    if current>=0 and previous==0:
        chg=1.0
    if current<0 and previous>0:
        chg=-1.0
    if current>0 and previous>0:
        chg=abs(current)/abs(previous)-1
    if current<0 and previous<0:
        chg=abs(current)/abs(previous)-1
        chg=-chg
    return round(chg*100,2)

df['chg'] = df.assign(previous =  df.groupby('CompanyId').stand_alone.shift(-1)).apply(get_change,axis=1)
```